# Prove that these metrics induce the same topology on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(\mathbb{C},d)$ denote the standard metric space defined over the complex plane with $d(z_1,z_2) = |z_1-z_2|$, and let $(\mathbb{C}_\infty, d_\infty)$ be the metric space defined over the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C}_\infty = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ by means of the stereographic projection, that is,
\begin{align*}
    d_{\infty}(z_1,z_2) = \frac{2|z_1-z_2|}{\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2}\sqrt{1+|z_2|^2}}, \hspace{0.5cm} d_{\infty}(z_1,\infty) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2}}.
\end{align*}
Denote by $B(a,r)$ an open ball in $(\mathbb{C},d)$ and by $B_\infty(a,r)$ an open ball in $(\mathbb{C}_\infty,d_\infty)$.

1. Show that for every $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $r > 0$ there exists a $\rho > 0$ so that $B_{\infty}(a,\rho) \subseteq B(a,r)$.
2. Show that for every $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $r > 0$ there exists a $\rho > 0$ so that $B(a,\rho) \subseteq B_{\infty}(a,r)$.

Basically I have tried setting $\rho = \frac{2r}{\sqrt{1+|a|^2}}$, for the first problem. However, I am confused for the scenario if $\infty \in B_\infty(a,r)$. I know once I prove both statements then it follows that we both metrics induce the same topology. But I am just having a hard time for the first problem.

Comment: As always in this forum, it is not enough merely to ask the question.  You have to show your own efforts.

Comment: @GEdgar, sorry about that meant to type it out.

Comment: The question of $\infty \in B_\infty(a,r)$ is a good one.  In 2. it doesn't matter, but in 1. we always have to choose $\rho$ small enough to ensure $\infty \notin B_\infty(a,\rho)$.